# C++ StringTokenizer for a multichar separator

Tags: c++, string, tokenize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split on substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739280/split-on-substring)

I want to separate an std::string by a two character separator, i.e. I'm looking for string tokenizer that can accept separators which are NOT a single character. Boost's tokenizer allows for multiple characters to be specified as separators, but this means that it'll consider *any* individual character as a separator, whilst what I want is to say that the separator is *a particular sequence* of characters, viz. a substring.

I'd initially thought I would quickly find the answer to this with a couple of google searches, but having just been proven wrong by a couple of wasted hours, I ask: ideas anyone?

Comment: You could always write your own using strstr() or similar.  It shouldn't take more than 30 minutes or so to write.

Answer (score 0):

QT's [QString::split()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#split) can do this.