# Boost::Split using whole string as delimiter

Tags: c++, string, boost, tokenize

I would like to know if there is a method using boost::split to split a string using whole strings as a delimiter. For example:

```
str = "xxaxxxxabcxxxxbxxxcxxx"
```

is there a method to split this string using `"abc"` as a a delimiter? Therefore returning:

Results would be the string `"xxaxxxx"` and `"xxxxbxxxcxxx"`.

I am aware of `boost::split` using the `"is_any_of"` predicate, however invoking `is_any_of("abc")` would result in splitting the string at the single character 'a', 'b', and 'c' as well, which is not what I want.

Comment: You should be able to use some combination of `equals` and the string value to be used as delimiter, but the specifics elude me right now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split on substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739280/split-on-substring)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`split_regex` as suggested by @Mythli is fine. If you don't want to deal with regex, you can use `ifind_all` algo, as is shown in this [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id2896235). You receive `iterator_range` (begin/end) of all occurrences of you delimiter. Your tokens are between them (and at the beginning and end of string).

Comment: Thanks, this solution fit my needs perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

Yes there is a way (this is a way I know, maybe there is a better way) Use `boost::algorithm::split_regex` to split character sequences where delimiters are regular expressions.

Example:

```
vector< string > result;
boost::algorithm::split_regex( result, str, regex( "^((?!abc)*abc(?!abc)*)*$" ) ) ;
copy( result.begin(), result.end(), ostream_iterator<string>( cout, "\n" ) ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works, however it requires boost to be built. Currently I am using header files only.

Comment: #include <boost/algorithm/string/regex.hpp>

Answer (score 0):

If you know what characters your input string is comprised of (e.g. a simple English sentence, with only EN characters), you can surround your word_delimiter with a special_symbol, replace all appearances of your word delimiter with it and split by the special_symbol.

For example, I used '%' here:

```
std::vector<std::string> sentence_parts;
boost::replace_all(sentence, word, "%" + word_delimiter + "%");
boost::split(sentence_parts, sentence, boost::is_any_of("%"));
```

**You need to be sure that your input string will never have the special symbol in it, otherwise it won't work well!**

Comment: Why would this be preferable to the more straightforward approach Mythli already described?

Comment: It's not necessarily preferable, it's another way to do it. Personally, I prefer not to deal with regexes...