# C++/Boost split a string on more than one character

Tags: c++, string, parsing, boost, tokenize

This is probably really simple once I see an example, but how do I generalize boost::tokenizer or boost::split to deal with separators consisting of more than one character?

For example, with "*_*_", neither of these standard splitting solutions seems to work :

```
boost::tokenizer<boost::escaped_list_separator<string> > 
        tk(myString, boost::escaped_list_separator<string>("", "____", "\""));
std::vector<string> result;
for (string tmpString : tk) {
    result.push_back(tmpString);
}
```

or

```
boost::split(result, myString, "___");
```

Comment: Please be specific about what "does not seem to work" means.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boost::Split using whole string as delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436968/boostsplit-using-whole-string-as-delimiter)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
boost::algorithm::split_regex( result, myString, regex( "___" ) ) ;
```

Comment: Can you please let me know that are the header files to be included to do this?

Comment: @Kadiam Try: #include <boost/algorithm/string_regex.hpp>

Answer (score 2):

Non-boost solution

```
vector<string> split(const string &s, const string &delim){
    vector<string> result;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    while(end!=string::npos){
        end = s.find(delim, start);
        result.push_back(s.substr(start, end-start));
        start = end + delim.length();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use splitregex instead: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/118708/boostalgorithmsplit-with-string-delimeters