# boost::split_iterator argument for class template missing

Tags: c++, boost, split

I have seen several examples that show how to use split_iterator but Visual Studio 2012 is showing me this error:
`Error: argument for class template "boost::algorithm::split_iterator" is missing`

This is my code:

```
...

#include "boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp"
#include "boost/algorithm/string/finder.hpp"

...

const std::string sintactic_production_rule_representation[] =
{
    ...

    "P &rarr; B eol P",
    "P &rarr; F eol P",

    ...
}

...

for(int i = 0; i < N_PRODUCTIONS_SINTLL; i++)
{
    std::vector<std::string> splittedProduction;
    boost::split_iterator(
        splittedProduction, 
        sintactic_production_rule_representation[i], 
        boost::first_finder("&rarr;")
    );
}
```

I have extracted `iter_find.hpp` and `finder.hpp` and dependences into the resource files with the boost bcp tool.

I also have tried `boost::split_iterator<std::string>(...)` getting a arguments does not match error.

Comment: `boost::split_iterator` is a class template, not a function. Maybe you want to use `boost::split`?

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov Can I use split to split with a string instead of a single character ?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/15789561/3153012 is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use the wrong boost function. As answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15789561/3153012 I can use `split_regex` to split with one or more character.