# C++ split string on multiple substrings

Tags: c++, string, boost

In C++, I'd like to something similar to:

[Split on substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739280/split-on-substring)

However, I'd like to specify *more than one* substring to split on. For example, I'd like to split on "+", "foo", "ba" for the string "fda+hifoolkjba4" into a vector of "fda", "hi", "lkj", "4". Any suggestions? Preferably within STL and Boost (I'd rather not have to incorporate the Qt framework or additional libraries if I can avoid it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with regular expressions, either from `<regex>` or `<boost/regex.hpp>`; the regular expression you need would be something like `(.*?)(\+|foo|ba)` (plus the final token).

Here's a cut-down example using Boost:

```
  std::string str(argv[1]);

  boost::regex r("(.*?)(\\+|foo|ba)");
  boost::sregex_iterator rt(str.begin(), str.end(), r), rend;

  std::string final;

  for ( ; rt != rend; ++rt)
  {
    std::cout << (*rt)[1] << std::endl;
    final = rt->suffix();
  }
  std::cout << final << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not too keen on using boost regex because the compiled libraries don't work so well on my mac. I can get them to work, but I need to point to my dynlib file (either in the executable directory or in a specified directory - not exactly ideal for distributing my work in standalone form), but that's an issue for a different question.

Comment: @daj: well, get a modern compiler then and use `<regex>` from the standard library :-) Same interface, just change `boost` to `std`.

Comment: That's great, I didn't realize it was in the standard library now. I do prefer Boost's split_regex() function for doing this (since iteration is replaced with a one-liner), which doesn't seem to have been added :-(

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using regular expression support in boost. See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_token_iterator.html) for an example.

here is a sample code that can split the string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;    

int main()
{

    boost::regex re("(\\+|foo|ba)");
    std::string s("fda+hifoolkjba4");

    boost::sregex_token_iterator i(s.begin(), s.end(), re, -1);
    boost::sregex_token_iterator j;
    while (i != j) {
       std::cout << *i++ << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```